# Passing ajax returned data to a function issue

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have question regarding the coeditor ajax call.

I am building my own custom plugin and I want to use the ajax returned data.

```
  function customPlugin(editor, data){
      return {
          title:'Audio Link',
          minWidth : 200,
          minHeight : 200,
          buttons : [CKEDITOR.dialog.okButton, CKEDITOR.dialog.cancelButton],
          contents: [
              {
                  id:'tab',
                  label: 'custom plugin',
                  elements: [
                      {
                      type:'select',
                      id:'select box',
                      items: [['data[0]',0],[data[1],0] ]
                      }
                  ]
              }
          ]
      }
  }

     //my own ajax wrapper that I can get the returned data
      ajax.onFinished = function(data){

      };

      CKEDITOR.dialog.add('customPlugin', function(editor){
           return customPlugin(editor,data);
      });
```

I tried the following

```
 ajax.onFinished = function(data){
       CKEDITOR.dialog.add('customPlugin', function(editor){
           return customPlugin(editor,data);
      });  
 }
```

`ckeditor` would give me error saying no definition of `customPlugin`.

I am not sure what to do next. Can someone give me a hint? Thanks!

Comment: Variable scope in JavaScript is function-based. Are you defining `customPlugin` inside another function and then trying to use it outside of that function?

Comment: I tried to pass ajax returned data to a function named customPlugin

Comment: Sounds very much like a scope issue. Also, really really similar to another recent [ckeditor] question :). Please check if `ajax.onFinished` and `customPlugin` are defined in the same scope. Show us the entire code if you want assistance.